# after making sdk level 31 to 33 changes done in code not reflected when build published in google play console in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, google-play, google-play-console

In react native application when changes in sdk level from31 to 33 and also change gradle version to 7.4.2 all the changes done are in debug mode and we saw all are okay in apk and
npx react-native run-android --variant=release using this command also are all okay but after upload aab by ./gradlew bundleRelease the published build contains only the previous things no new changes are reflected in the current version , i can't find whats going wrong here ? please help...